# select records for same month with query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table  calendar and chart.In calendar table I have  dvalue and monthwithyear fields and in chart table I have 3 fields meeting_start_date ,call_start_date and month

dcalendar table

```
"2020-08-01 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-08-02 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-08-03 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-08-04 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-08-05 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
...                           ...  
"2020-08-29 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-08-30 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-08-31 00:00:00"   "August-2020"
"2020-09-01 00:00:00"   "September-2020"
"2020-09-02 00:00:00"   "September-2020"
"2020-09-03 00:00:00"   "September-2020"
 ...                        ...
"2020-09-29 00:00:00"   "September-2020"
"2020-09-30 00:00:00"   "September-2020"
```

chart table

```
id     month          meeting_start_date    call_start_date
1     "August-2020"   "2020-08-13 00:00:00" "2020-08-06 00:00:00"
2     "August-2020"   "2020-09-10 00:00:00" "2020-07-16 00:00:00"
3     "August-2020"   "2020-07-10 00:00:00" "2020-06-16 00:00:00"
4     "August-2020"   "2020-08-18 00:00:00" "2020-07-22 00:00:00"
5     "September-2020"  "2020-09-16 00:00:00"   "2020-08-04 00:00:00"
6     "September-2020"  "2020-09-21 00:00:00"   "2020-07-07 00:00:00"
7     "September-2020"  "2020-09-03 00:00:00"   
8     "September-2020"  "2020-08-07 00:00:00"   "2020-08-02 00:00:00"
9     "September-2020"  "2020-07-30 00:00:00"   "2020-07-30 00:00:00"
```

dcalender table have all date in august and september.In august month I want to check either meeting or call start date is in august and for the month september I want to check either meeting or call start date is in september.

so I want to choose only the id 1 and 4 and in september 5,6,7 .
I have tried as

```
select a.id from chart_table as a 
    left join dcalendar as b on a.month=b.monthwithyear
```

and am stuck with where condition

Comment: There is really No Point in the `month` column. For a start you can get the month from the other date columns and secondly as it is presumably a text column you cannot easily apply date functions to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM chart
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), '%d-%M-%Y')) 
            IN (MONTH(meeting_start_date), MONTH(call_start_date));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0343fa5f3c313a800a0b50750a425f5c)

`dcalendar` table not needed for current task.

Comment: how can I use it in laravel query

Comment: @user3386779 use raw SQL in OnWhere.

Comment: tried as  $report_details=$report_details->Where(DB::raw(MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-', `month`), '%d-%M-%Y')) 
            IN (MONTH(meeting_start_date), MONTH(call_start_date))));  getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'IN' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' .  What I did wrong can please sort out

Comment: Where are quote or dquote chars which must wrap the string literal with the condition text???